# Qt "Failed to create D3D shaders."

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qt-creator

QML works fine until i upgradate my graphic driver, after that all the programs i code in QtCreator show me this at the log console and don't show the program windows elements (like images, or shapes).

> QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( qt_Matrix ): shader program is not linked QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
>
> shader compilation failed:  "Failed to create D3D shaders.\n"
>   QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders. Failed to create
>   D3D shaders.

I don't know much about what is OpenGl, but i think that it is for 3D things. Why it is a problem in my programs, if i only use 2D shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--Solved

I just updated again the drivers using DriverBooster and then **uninstall DirectX and reinstalling**.